# Django Multiple Types of Users, one base usertype?

Tags: python, django, rest

I am attempting to create a food delivery app clone. Which has two types of users Restaurant User and Customers. I want the restaurant user to be able to also be customers, using the same login info.

This is how my models are setup right now:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    user_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='restaurant')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)  

class Customer(models.Model):
    user_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customer')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

I don't believe this works as intended. Would it be better to create a base usertype, for login and shared information, like user_name, full_name, phone?

I created the following for that purpose:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='CustomUser')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

But I'm not sure how to connect this between the other user models. Or if this is even the proper way to do it.

So how can I achieve what I am trying to do, what would my models look like?

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

You can use the custom user as the base class. So you could pass that custom model as such:

```
class Restaurant(CustomUser):
    user_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='restaurant')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)  

class Customer(CustomUser):
    user_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customer')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Also, you should declare the CustomUser as abstract.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='CustomUser')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: Thank you! Most of the examples in the docs you linked don't repeat fields. Like user_name would only be in the base (CustomUser) but not in the others (Restaurant and Customer).  Im guessing it would just overwrite the CustomUser user_name with the Restaurant/Customer one right? Making no difference in application?

Comment: You don't have to repeat the fields found in the base model in other models that inherit from that base model. If you did repeat the fields I'm not sure if it would overwrite the field or throw an error like `field already exists`.

Comment: With this solution one would end up having Two user models (for authentication, also would be a little complex to get that working), a One To One with the CustomUser would be better and much simpler.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat how would I do a OneToOne with CustomUser?

Comment: @musicalears just set the OneToOneField to the CustomUser model. If you declare the CustomUser model after your Restaurant and Customer class you may write `'CustomUser'` in string instead instead or better yet `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`. Also for some reason you inherit from AbstractUser yet have a One To One with the User model, this doesn't make sense your CustomUser model would **replace** the default User model.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='restaurant')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class RestaurantStaff(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='staff')
    staff = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='staff')
    employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Note: Never duplicate the columns, if you inherit the same model in two other model, both of those model will have same fields/columns of the inherited model.

Here is the explaination of model structure:

1. There is only one CustomUser model that holds the data for all users(customer, restaurant owner, staff)
2. Restaurant model holds the data related to restaurant(its owner link, name, address, restaurant phone number)
3. RestaurantStaff model hold the relation of a restaurant and a user(which is the restaurant staff), so there you can add more fields like, "start_date", "termination_date", "post"

Your choice of field types are incorrect(example phone number should be interger, but you choose character, email should be email field, but you choose character). Use what django already provide as it helps in validation and serialization in API.